# All Teams Recordings to go to a designated Sharepoint folder

Tags: microsoft-teams

I am aware of the recent change to how Teams stores recorded meetings.

Is there anything we can do so instead of having group meetings recordings being stored in the Personal OneDrive for Business (under "Recordings") to have them just stored in a folder in SharePoint?

At the moment its a manual job to move them I was hoping there is something a bit more automated to get them into SharePoint.
I have setup a recurring PowerAutomate Flow (https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Move-files-in-folder-from-OneDrive-to-Sharepoint-into-a-newly/td-p/673833#) to do it, but this ONLY works for me.

Any ideas or insight will be appreciated.